# Is there a way to create BottomBar using SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios13

I want to create a *bottom bar* which should be common for all my page. Here I am posting the image:

[image: Here]

I know how to do it using storyboard. But how can I do it in SwiftUI?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This kind of view is called tab bar in iOS and in SwiftUI  it is called `TabView`. It is declared like this:

```
var body: some View {
    TabView {
        Text("Favourites Screen")
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "heart.fill")
                Text("Favourites")
        }
        Text("Friends Screen")
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "person.fill")
                Text("Friends")
        }
        Text("Nearby Screen")
            .tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "mappin.circle.fill")
                Text("Nearby")
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Tab bar]

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use Label view for giving name & icon of the tab:

```
struct BottomTabBar: View {
    var body: some View {
        TabView{
            Text("Profile Contents")
                .tabItem{
                    Label("Profile",systemImage: "person.fill")
                }
            Text("Tv Contents")
                .tabItem{
                    Label("Tv",systemImage: "tv.fill")
                }
        }
    }

}
```